# What is probability of a relation being reflexive, symmetric, and both?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have a set [n]. If we take 1 random relation from all the possible relations on that set, what is the probability of that relation being reflexive, symmetric, both, or neither? I know that the total number of relations is $2^{n^2}$ the number of reflexive relations is $2^{n^2-n}$. How do I go about finding the number of symmetric functions and the other cases?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: For each element $~a,~$ either $~a \sim a,~$ or $~\neg (a\sim ~a).~$  What is the probability for one specific element?  For the relation to be reflexive, it must hold for all $~n~$ elements.  You can regard this as $~n~$ independent events, that must all hold.

Comment: One issue to consider is how many different possible relations that there are on the set of $~n~$ elements.  Considering that the $~\sim~$ relationship is not necessarily commutative, there are $~n^2~$ possible $~(a,b)~$ element combinations to consider.  For each combination, either $~a \sim b,~$ or $~\neg (a\sim b).$  Therefore, there are $~\displaystyle 2^{\left(n^2\right)}~$ different possible relations on the set with $~n~$ elements.  The point of this comment is not to answer the question but instead to expand the *intuition* of the OP (i.e. original poster).

Comment: Hint: For symmetric, think in terms of pair of elements $a, b$ with $a < b$. How many pairs of elements there are? What is the probability for each pair to respect the symmetric condition?

Comment: Symmetric relations is easy, but I think transitive relations is much more complicated and may be an open problem.  OEIS will have details.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noted, the number of reflexive relations is $2^{n^2-n}$.

For finding the number of symmetric relations, what matters is which *pairs* of numbers you choose to be related. There are ${n\choose 2}+n$ such pairs (including the pairs with only one number). Thus, there are $2^{{n\choose 2}+n}$ symmetric relations on $[n]$.

The number of relations which are both symmetric and reflexive is simply $2^{n\choose 2}$ as for each pair of distinct elements there is a choice for whether or not they are related.

So to calculate the number of relations which are neither, I guess you can use the [Principle of Inclusion Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The number of functions which are either reflexive or symmetric is equal to $2^{n^2-n}+2^{{n\choose 2}+n}-2^{n\choose 2}$.

Simply subtract this from the total number of relations, $2^{n^2},$ to get the number of relations which are neither reflexive nor symmetric.